# get current datetime in the right format with jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to get the current datetime in the format `2015-09-24 09:30:30` with jquery, is there anyway to do this? I tried `$.now()` and got `1443085060076`, with `Date($.now())` I got `Thu Sep 24 2015 10:59:32 GMT+0200 (Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit)`. Both not what I want.

Comment: The duplicated is including a new plugin. If you don't want to include it, see my answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's simple:

```
var d = new Date($.now());
alert(d.getDate()+"-"+(d.getMonth() + 1)+"-"+d.getFullYear()+" "+d.getHours()+":"+d.getMinutes()+":"+d.getSeconds());
```

See the API:

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Date

See it working:

https://jsfiddle.net/g35uxqtp/171/

Comment: thanks, works fine. except it show month and day in single digit. I found another way to get what I want `var d = new Date().toISOString().substr(0,19).replace('T',' ');`

Comment: Ok, so my answer is an example to show how to format easily a date. If this answer is useful for you please, upvote it.

Comment: `d.getDay()` is the number of the day of the week and should be `d.getDate()` for the number of day in the month. `d.getMonth()` should be `(d.getMonth()+1)` because `getMonth` counts from 0.

Comment: You're totally right @Fid , answer edited

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude You still have `d.getDay()` instead of `d.getDate()`. Today is `17-10-2018` and the above code would return `3-10-2018`, because it is the third day of the week.

Answer (score 4):

Straight JS will work to. You don't need to use jQuery.

```
var d = new Date();
var o = {year:'numeric', month:'2-digit', day:'2-digit', hour:'2-digit', minute:'2-digit', second:'2-digit'};
d.toLocaleDateString('en-US', o);
```

More information on the toLocaleDateString method 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString

Comment: I get `09/24/2015, 12:13:55 PM` from that, not what I wanted.

Comment: Good appointment. I upvote you because I didn't know this technique. Thank you!